# Refresh ActiveRecord result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to refresh ActiveRecord result in "rails way"? Example:

```
stuff = Stuff.find(:id)
a = stuff.x   # a = 3
(at this time field value in database stuff.x changed to 7 )
a = stuff.x   # a = 3 but I need here 7
```

Is it possible to do something like stuff.refresh_data to re-execute query?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `reload`. In your case you would write `stuff.reload`

Here is the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload).

Comment: Spent 3 hours debugging why my stupid object didn't update .. and found this. Thank you!